# How do I upload a pandas dataframe containing lists to Google BigQuery array and structs format?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I would like to use pandas to push a dataframe into a BigQuery table that has arrays and structs

The Bigquery Table looks like this:
col_a (int), col_b (string), col_c.A (struct with Array Subtype0), col_c.B (struct with int subtype)

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

col_a (type int), col_b (string), col_c( list of objects), col_d( int).

Is there a way to upload pandas dataframes to bigquery tables with structs and arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that

```
import google.cloud
from google.cloud import bigquery


def save_df_to_bq(args,dataframe,csv_name):



print("Length of the incoming dataframe :-->" , len(dataframe))

print(dataframe.iloc[[0]])

client = bigquery.Client()

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id,project_id)

 schema = [
     bigquery.SchemaField('col_a ', 'dttype'),
     bigquery.SchemaField('col_b ', 'dttype'),
     bigquery.SchemaField('col_c ', 'dttype'),

 ]      

acc_table_id = str(random.randint(100000,100000*1000000))
# table_ref = dataset_ref.table(acc_table_id)
# table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=schema)
# table = client.create_table(table)  # API request
# print("Table created..")

# acc_table_id = str(random.randint(100000,100000*1000000))
acc_table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id,project_id).table(acc_table_id)
job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(dataframe, acc_table_ref, location="US")
job.result()
```

Comment: does not work. Apparently using pandas dataframes to a struct table is not allowed